# Smallest integer satisfiing "Modulo-Prime" inequalities

Tags: prime-numbers

Given N prime numbers ($p_1$,...,$p_N$) and N integer intervals (with N lower bounds ($l_1$, ,...,$l_N$) and N upper bounds ($u_1$,...,$u_N$) where $0 < l_k < u_k < p_k$ ).

Is there an efficient algorithm to find the smallest integer $x$ satisfying the following N inequalities:

$l_1$ <= $x$ mod $p_1$ <= $u_1$ 
...
$l_N$ <= $x$ mod $p_N$ <= $u_N$

Comment: One simple algorithm would be to start at $1$ or $0$ (depending on whether you want positive integers or nonnegative integers) and loop through the inequalities, every time you encounter an inequality that isn't satisfied, increasing the number by the minimum amount to make that equality satisfied (which is easily calculated), halting when you've made it through a full loop without increasing the number.

Comment: Possibly OP is writing *effective* whilst meaning *efficient*.

Comment: For what it's worth, the following problem is NP-complete: given a collection $\{(a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_n,b_n)\}$ of ordered pairs of positive integers, with $a_i\le b_i$ for all $i$, is there an integer $x$ such that, for all $i$, $x\not\equiv a_i\pmod{b_i}$? This is [AN2] on page 249 of Garey & Johnson, the reference is Stockmeyer & Meyer, Word problems requiring exponential time, Proc 5th Ann ACM Symp on Theory of Computing, pp 1-9.